# Profile files *refuse* to delete

Tags: windows-server-2003, files

I have a problem with some profile files that refuse to be deleted. I need to nuke these files so that one particular user can actually log on to this terminal server.

Taking the server off-line, and yanking out the files with a live CD. (which would be my normal recourse) is out the question as this baby runs 24/7 serving about 50 people at any one time. (yes I know, we should have a redundant terminal server, but try explaining that to management when they are already so happy with the existing one!).

Can anyone recommend an app or utility to help me out here?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to do this.

Comment: Unlocker helped to deleted most of them

Answer (score 0):

A program may have open handles on the files, so Windows won't let you delete them.

You could check with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to see what has a handle open on them, and potentially close what is locking the file. If it's a system process however, you may be stuck with a reboot depending on what the system process is.

Answer (score 0):

How are you deleting them? Are you trying to delete them directly from Documents and Settings? If so, that's the wrong way. You should be deleting them from the User Profiles settings of the system properties. When selecting the profile if the delete button is grayed out it means that the profile hasn't been unloaded completely. A reboot will fix that. You should install the User Profile Hive Cleanup Service on the server as well.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b286e6d-8912-4e18-b570-42470e2f3582&displaylang=en